# Is there a resolution limit to electron microscopes?

Tags: waves, electrons, wavelength, microscopy

Is resolution limited only by the wavelength of the electron? Because then I would presume there is no limit to resolution as you could lower the wavelength of an electron by increasing the voltage of the microscope.

lambda=h/(2*e*U*m)^1/2

Comment: The beam size is limited by electron repulsion. Charging is also an issue.  See for example https://www.ou.edu/research/electron/bmz5364/resolutn.html and https://www.labx.com/resources/limitations-of-using-electron-microscopes-to-view-specimens/40

Comment: @my2cts - in a normal TEM there is one electron in the machine at a time, on average. Low beam currents, relativistic electrons and all that. Still, beam spread is an issue, but not from space charge.

Answer (score 1):

There are practical limits. My favorite example is the original SLAC electron accelerator. With a beam tube 10,000 feet long, it could make electrons with short enough wavelengths that they could probe the insides of a proton- and discover 3 little point particles running around in there. But it occupied a lot of real estate, cost many millions of dollars to build, and their electric bills were substantial.